# What are the keycodes for event listeners in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am making a Chrome Extension called simple dark mode. The goal is to have the F12 key run a function. This is what I have.

```
const KEY_HANDLERS = {
    KeyT: () => location.replace('http://thisisatest.com'),
  };
  
  document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
  
      const handler = KEY_HANDLERS[e.code];
      
      if (handler) {
        handler();
        return;
      }
      
      console.log(Key Pressed);
  });
```

My goal again is to make it F12, but when I search for keycodes, I get numbers? Where can I find javascript keycodes such as Key12??

Comment: My bad, not key 12. F12!!

Comment: `keycode` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode). Use `e.key` instead. With that, you can simply check `e.key == 'F12'`

Comment: I try this, but I get an error, can you please give me an example with my code?

Comment: If this is exactly the code you're using, your error may be `console.log(Key Pressed)` not having quotes around the text inside. But other than that you would have to post your error.

Comment: please give me a minute

Comment: https://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: Ok I'm not sure how to test this code myself, but try changing `KEY_HANDLERS` to `'F12': () => location.replace('http://thisisatest.com')` and `const handler = KEY_HANDLERS[e.key]`

Comment: Beware with such key bindings. Your users may very well have a behavior already assigned to this key. For instance F12 that you wish to use is very commonly used to open the browser's dev-tools. And as an extension you even need to be careful with the ones that could be used by the current website.

Comment: @Kaiido Opening the dev tools is assumably exactly what OP is trying to achieve to prevent.

Comment: @connexo why would they need to change anything then? I believe their goal is rather to toggle between light/dark mode themes, or according to the code we see, to navigate to another page. And they chose F12 because it's at a nice place on the keyboard, without realizing that place is already taken.